# lme4: bootstrap confidence intervals using sample data not in model

Tags: r, lme4, statistics-bootstrap

I want to calculate the confidence interval for a model parameter (residual SD) divided by the mean of a variable not included in the model. Example:

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix

set.seed(1)

mod <- lmer(angle ~ recipe + (1|replicate), data = cake)

calc_stats <- function(model) {
    recipeA <- fixef(model)[[1]] # Get intercept from model
    sd_components <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(model))[['sdcor']] # Get variance components (SD)
    sd_between = sd_components[1]
    sd_within = sd_components[2]
    
    c(
        recipeA = recipeA,
        sd_between = sd_between,
        sd_within = sd_within
    )
}

confint(mod, method="boot", FUN = calc_stats, nsim = 100)
#>                2.5 %    97.5 %
#> recipeA    29.095426 36.722292
#> sd_between  3.800349  9.382943
#> sd_within   5.044569  6.078210
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I want to calculate a CI for sd_within/mean(temperature), where temperature is a variable in the dataframe, but not included in the model.

The problem is that temperature is not in `mod@frame`. Therefore i cannot access it for the bootstrap refits of the model.

(My first idea was to simply add it to the model object `mod@frame <- cake`, but it is of cause lost when refitting the model).

Comment: Are you aware that `method="boot"` uses *parametric* bootstrapping, so that it's not actually resampling the data set? That is, it's "resampling" values by simulating from the model and refitting.  Thus `mean(temperature)` will be the same for every bootstrap replicate. Would you like an example of how to do (nested) *nonparametric* bootstrapping (i.e. via sampling replicates with replacement, then sampling observations within replicates by replacement) with this example?

Comment: I was not aware that parametric bootstrapping did not involve resampling the data (will have to read up on this ;) ) If nonparametric bootstrapping would be appropriate here, an example would be a great help.

Comment: I found the `lmeresampler` package, which implements several parametric/resampling-based methods, but so far I haven't come up with a method that works with the package (for exactly the reasons your example doesn't work - the model that gets passed to the bootstrap-statistics function only contains the model frame ... a **very** ugly solution would be (if the predictors are unique for every observation in the original data set) to match up the values in the model frame in the model passed to the stats function with the original data set ...

Comment: The predictors are only categorical, so (un)fortunatly that would not work :) Would a nonparametric bootstrap be statistically reasonable solution for this type of problem. I.e refitting the model on resamples and calculating my desired statistics for each refitted model. My model is quick to fit, so it shouldn't be a problem computationally. I didn't dare do it, as I thought there might be a statistical reason you didn't implement it in bootMer().